# Kernel density estimation in ggplot with geom_density

Tags: r, ggplot2

Can somebody explain how the example graphic in the [ggplot documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_density.html) is estimated?

So, as I can read in the description, the estimation with `geom_density()` is a kernel density estimation. Though, kernel density estimations are constructed to be a probability measure, but the area of the graphic is obviously not 1, but something about 5.

[image]

Can somebody describe the math behind the graphic?

Comment: If this question refer more to Cross Validated, please transfer it...

Answer (score 0):

The total area of the graph doesn't mean anything. The fact that the vertical axis goes from 0 to 1 *does* mean something.

The graph shows the *conditional probability* of each category, based on the value of `carat`.

For example, let's take `carat = 1`. Here, `ideal` diamonds take up a large chunk of the vertical space, as shown by the large pink area. Conversely, `fair` diamonds take up only a small fraction, as shown by the small red/orange area. So we can say that more 1 carat diamonds are likely to be ideal than fair. Now let's take `carat = 5`. Here, the red/orange area takes up all the vertical space, and all other categories are negligible. This means that (nearly) all 5-carat diamonds are fair.

(And the Y-axis label "count" isn't great; it should be more like "probability".)

Comment: Okay, I know how to interpret the graph, but I don't know how to calculate the values, so that they are forced into an interval from 0 to 1.